# Is it possible to extract Junit results into Xls file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit

I have my selenium test suit in the eclipse and I have used JUnit to execute tests.

Test suite is executed as expected and results are displayed in eclipse

I want to extract these results of  test cases into xls file.

Is it possible to extract the test results such way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know an easy way to get the test results from Eclipse; it doesn't write them into a file.

If you really want to do it in Eclipse, then you will have to write a plugin.

A more simple solution is to add a build system like Maven or Gradle to your project. They will run JUnit with a command line runner that writes the test results to an XML file. You can then use tools like and XML parser and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/) to create Excel sheets from that.

Comment: +1, would also like to add that writing the excel file this way means your reports are not dependent on eclipse at all so others can run them or you can include the report as part of a Continious Integration pipeline.